# WPF (.net 3.5) Binding to number (int, dbl) but allow user to input nothing

Tags: wpf, validation, binding

If you bind to a view-model property that is a nullable double (or int) how do you allow a user to specify nothing.

I'm looked into validation but I can't see how I could get that to help.

It seems like if a textbox is blanked out WPF sees it as an empty string and then doesn't put the into  the vm proptery.

So 2 ways around it I can think of is:

1. vm property is a string which is
   validated and updates the backing
   model.
2. special code that indicates no value (in my case the dbl should not
   be neg so -9 could be a null...but
   don't like the idea of magic
   numbers)

Any other ideas?  Am I missing something?

cody

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set [TargetNullValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue.aspx) to the empty string on the binding.  When WPF sees this value, it will set the source to null instead of trying to convert the value.

```
{Binding TargetNullValue=''}
```

Comment: +1. I've been doing so much SL3 work, didn't even know this handy feature was available in WPF (and now SL4).

Comment: That is brilliant. I've been looking for an elegant way to handle this for ages.